# why are there two different view when I import the same Document List?

Tags: document-library, document

I added an app part on a separate page and the document library came in looking strange who do i switch it back to the original view?
[image]

Comment: Hi @Sean, welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution :)

Answer (score 0):

To change the view, try to do the following:

- Edit your page.
- Edit your web part.
- In `Selected Views` > select your required view.

[image]